# Is there an easier way to perform this type of query

Tags: mysql, database, join, left-join, inner-join

I have spend most of the day creating this to finally get the result that I am looking for.  I am not great with SQL but there must be an easier way to achieve this.

The query is

```
SELECT *, 
   Date(review_date 
        + INTERVAL review_period_weeks week) AS next_review_date 
FROM   (SELECT * 
    FROM   (SELECT tbl_candidate_temp.id, 
                   tbl_candidate_temp.last_name, 
                   tbl_candidate_temp.first_name, 
                   tbl_candidate_temp.ni_number, 
                   tbl_candidate_temp.date_of_birth, 
                   tbl_candidate_temp.start_date, 
                   tbl_candidate_temp.expected_end_date, 
                   tam_company_main.id   AS company_id, 
                   tam_company_main.name AS company_name, 
                   review_period_weeks 
            FROM   (SELECT tam_candidate.id, 
                           tam_candidate.last_name, 
                           tam_candidate.first_name, 
                           tam_candidate.ni_number, 
                           tam_candidate.date_of_birth, 
                           tam_candidate.start_date, 
                           tam_candidate.expected_end_date, 
                           tam_candidate.company_main_lu, 
                           review_period_weeks 
                    FROM   tam_candidate 
                           INNER JOIN (SELECT tam_candidate.id 
                                              AS 
                                              id, 
                                              tam_country.name 
                                              AS 
                                              award_country_name, 
tam_country.review_period_weeks AS 
review_period_weeks 
FROM   tam_candidate 
INNER JOIN tam_country 
    ON 
tam_candidate.award_country_lu = 
tam_country.id 
WHERE  reviewer = 1) AS 
tbl_candidate 
ON tam_candidate.id = tbl_candidate.id) AS 
tbl_candidate_temp 
INNER JOIN tam_company_main 
ON 
tbl_candidate_temp.company_main_lu = tam_company_main.id) 
AS tbl_candidate_temp2 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT tam_candidate_review.candidate_lu, 
review_date 
FROM   tam_candidate_review 
ORDER  BY review_date DESC) AS tbl_review_temp 
ON tbl_candidate_temp2.id = tbl_review_temp.candidate_lu) AS 
tbl_candidate_temp3
```

The candidate table contains the main data, eg name, NI number etc

The country contains the county names, as well as the number of weeks that reviews must take place in that country

The company table contains the names of companies

the reviews tables contain a date, and a candidate number

reviwer is the id of the currently logged in reviewer.

My goal is to have the following columns:

```
id < candidate id
last_name
first_name
ni_number
date_of_birth
start_date
expected_end_date
company_id 
company_name<lookup from company table 
review_period_weeks<lookup from country
candidate_lu
review_date < last review 
next_review_date < last review + review_period_weeks WEEKS
```

Comment: -Facepalm-  Create a [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) please.

Comment: I Think this is what you wanted http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c859/1/0 - I have just found a problem too, it displays a full row for each review, I would like to only include the most recent review. (One row per candidate with next review date calculated based on the most recent review)  Thanks